# Can I update a foreign key based on another tables foreign key change?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

```
create table `company_building` (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table `job` (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  company_building_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (company_building_id) REFERENCES company_building(id)
);

create table `cost_detail` (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  company_building_id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT `a_constraint` FOREIGN KEY (company_building_id) REFERENCES 
company_building_id(id) ON UPDATE SET NULL
);
```

Say I have this sort of set up and I want it to update `cost_detail.company_building_id` when `job.company_building_id` gets updated.

`ON UPDATE CASCADE` will only work if when `company_building.id` is changed but not `job.company_building_id`. Is there any way using triggers or maybe some foreign key magic I don't know about?

**EDIT:**

to elaborate we have a structure like

```
group1
   v
group2
   v
group3
   v
cost_detail < other group1 < other group2
```

and imagine costs just being a $ amount. essentially I want to be able to see all the costs associated to group2 OR the costs associated with other_group1 OR costs associated with group1 and other group2.

to do this I would just write something like
`select * from cost_detail where group2_id = ? and other_group1_id = ?;` instead of doing a join

Comment: If the cost_detail is related to the job, and not the company_building; it should be referencing the job, not the company_building. Example, if multiple jobs referenced the same company_building, and one job was changed to reference a different one; should ALL cost_details move? some? none?

Comment: the cost_detail would actually be related to everything. so it would also point to the job. but to answer your question, all the cost_details would move. (ideally)

Comment: to clarify we have a tree structure hierachy with cost_detail being the lowest braches of the tree and instead of joining back against the entire tree we want all the FKs to also live in the cost_detail (for easier queries since there's a lot of data analysis on cost_detail). But anytime anything in the hierarchy changes we want it to be reflected in the cost_detail table too

Comment: Regarding "all cost_details would move", so "moving" any job from one cb to another would move all cd, and leave all other jobs behind with no associated cd, and no cd associated with the former cb anymore? I think you may need to elaborate on the hierarchy a little more since the data structure you've presented does not actually reflect it in any sensible way.

Comment: updated my question